# How may we show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}{{\cos\left({2x\over \pi}\right)-\cos^2\left({2x\over \pi}\right)}\over x^2}\cdot\ln(x)\,\mathrm dx=-\ln(2)?$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

**Simple closed form** given by this complicated integral

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{{\cos\left({2x\over \pi}\right)-\cos^2\left({2x\over \pi}\right)}\over x^2}\cdot\ln(x)\,\mathrm dx=-\ln(2)\tag1$$

**Making an attempt:**

Splitting $(1)$ results in the integral to be diverges.

$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{{\cos\left({2x\over \pi}\right)-\cos^2\left({2x\over \pi}\right)}\over x^a}\cdot\ln(x)\,\mathrm dx\tag2$$

$$I'(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{{\cos\left({2x\over \pi}\right)-\cos^2\left({2x\over \pi}\right)}\over x^a}\,\mathrm dx\tag3$$

$$I'(2)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{{\cos\left({2x\over \pi}\right)-\cos^2\left({2x\over \pi}\right)}\over x^2}\,\mathrm dx\tag4$$

$u={2x\over \pi}$

$$I'(2)={2\over \pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}{{\cos\left({u}\right)-\cos^2\left({u}\right)}\over u^2}\,\mathrm du=I_1-I_2\tag5$$
Recall from table of integral, I was thinking of using $(6)$ for $I_1$ but it is only valid for $0\le p\le 1$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cos x\over x^p}\,\mathrm dx={\pi\over 2\Gamma(p)\cos(p\pi/2)}\tag6$$

**How may we prove (1)?**

Comment: Frullani's theorem could be very usefull here

Comment: If you (OP) should follow the approach in the question, you should introduce $I(a)$ without the logarithm in the integral. Then, the logarithm appears when differentiating. As it stands now, it is wrong.

Comment: I am really curious: what is your source for the (sometimes rather involved) integrals you propose?

Comment: First of all, I am thankful for your great effort in answering most of the questions. I took most ideas from this site and other like wolfram and Wikipedia and I just play around with it using CAS plus some algebra and thoughts.** Nothing so special how I got these formulas. ** Nearly every formula I gave I gave the answer too. I don't gave formulas without closed form because the integrals could be unsolvable. I will try my best and link the sources next time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\cos\pars{2x/\pi} - \cos^{2}\pars{2x/\pi} \over x^{2}}\,\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}
{1 - \cos^{2}\pars{2x/\pi} \over x^{2}}\,\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{\infty}
{1 - \cos\pars{2x/\pi} \over x^{2}}\,\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\sin^{2}\pars{2x/\pi} \over x^{2}}\,\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{\infty}
{2\sin^{2}\pars{x/\pi} \over x^{2}}\,\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\ln\pars{\pi x \over 2}\,\dd x -
{2 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\ln\pars{\pi x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\bracks{\ln\pars{1 \over 2}}\,\dd x =
\bbx{\ds{-\ln\pars{2}}}
\end{align}

Comment: An interesting technique!

Comment: @Latte' Thanks. Just basic Trigonometry.

Comment: That is power(understanding), solving big problem with basic formula.(+1)

Comment: Concise and complete (+1).

Comment: (+1) This hurts so bad, I did not notice such splendid cancellation :D

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks. Any time I see a $\cos$ I think in $1 - \cos$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks. I was surprised too.

Answer (score 9):

I will propose an alternative (but extremely similar to tired's) approach.
By the Laplace transform, for any $k>0$ and any $\alpha\in(1,3)$ we have

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(kx)}{x^\alpha}\,dx = k^{\alpha-1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{\alpha}}\,dx =\frac{k^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s^{\alpha-2}}{1+s^2}\,ds\tag{1}$$
and the last integral can be computed through the Beta function. In particular we get:

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(kx)}{x^\alpha}\,dx = \frac{\pi\,k^{\alpha-1}}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(a-2)\right)\Gamma(\alpha)} \tag{2}$$
and by differentiating both sides with respect to $\alpha$ we simply get:
$$ g(k)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(kx)}{x^2}\log(x)\,dx = \frac{k\pi}{2}\left(1-\gamma-\log k\right) \tag{3}$$
so the original integral equals:

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{2x}{\pi}\right)-\cos^2\left(\frac{2x}{\pi}\right)}{x^2}\log(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\,g\left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)-g\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)=\color{red}{-\log 2}\tag{4} $$
as wanted.

Comment: Jack, how does one arrive at the RHS of $(1)$?  It's 1:16 a.m. and I'm too tired to proceed.

Comment: @Dr.MV: Laplace transform of $1-\cos x$, inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{x^\alpha}$.

Comment: Yes, I thought so.  But doing calculations in my head, I couldn't get a reciprocal $\Gamma$ term.  Alas, I found a piece of paper and pen, and performed the integration around the branch cut.  Then, applying the reflection principal recovered the result herein.  Thanks Jack and (+1).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I am surprised that nobody mentioned [Frullani's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html).

Answer (score 8):

Define

$$
I(b)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(b x)-\cos^2(b x)}{x^2}\log(x)
$$

so the integral in question is $I(2/\pi)$. Now

$$
-I'(b)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(b x)(1-2\cos(b x))}{x}\log(x)\underbrace{=}_{xb\rightarrow y}\\I'(1)-\log(b)\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)(1-2\cos(x))}{x}=I'(1)
$$

or

$$
I(b)=-bI'(1)+c
$$

now $I'(1)$ can be calculated pretty straightfowardy from using $2\cos(x)\sin(x)=\sin(2x)$ .

$$
I'(1)=\log(2)\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\log(2)\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Afterwards the only thing left is to fix $c$ which can be done by observing that $\lim_{b\rightarrow 0}I(b)=0$ which follows from the Taylorexpansion of $\cos(bx)-\cos^2(bx)$. This means

> $$
> I(b)=-b\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)
> $$

from which it follows that $I(2/\pi)=-\log(2)$ as proposed

Comment: Omg , did you just forget to write $dx$ for each integral :O .

Comment: How do you justify differentiation under the integral sign?

Comment: @JanG that is a very good (and non-trivial) question. since i am very busy today i try to answer it tomorrow

Comment: $@$tired Now I think that I know how to justify the differentiation. Use Cauchy condition for uniform convergence and integration by parts to prove that the integral involved in $I'(b)$ converges uniformly.

Comment: Feynman's Trick gets a (+1)

Answer (score 7):

I will propose an answer based on integration by parts.

Put $b = \frac{2}{\pi}$. We get
\begin{gather*}
I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos(bx)-\cos^2(bx)}{x^2}\log(x)\, dx = \left[-\dfrac{\cos(bx)-\cos^2(bx)}{x}\log(x)\right]_{0}^{\infty}+\\[2ex]b\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2\sin(bx)\cos(bx)-\sin(bx)}{x}\log(x)\, dx + \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos(bx)-\cos^2(bx)}{x^2}\, dx = 0+bI_1+I_2\tag{1}
\end{gather*}
where
\begin{gather*}
I_1 =\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2\sin(bx)\cos(bx)-\sin(bx)}{x}\log(x)\, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(2bx)}{x}\log(x)\, dx -\\[2ex]
\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(bx)}{x}\log(x)\, dx =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(bx)}{x}\log\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\, dx -\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(bx)}{x}\log(x)\, dx =\\[2ex] -\log(2)\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(bx)}{x}\, dx = -\log(2)\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\, dx = -\log(2)\dfrac{\pi}{2}= -\log(2)\dfrac{1}{b}
\end{gather*}
and
\begin{gather*}
I_2 = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos(bx)-\cos^2(bx)}{x^2}\, dx = \left[-\dfrac{\cos(bx)-\cos^2(bx)}{x}\right]_{0}^{\infty} +\\[2ex] b\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2\sin(bx)\cos(bx)-\sin(bx)}{x}\, dx = 0.
\end{gather*}
Consequently $I = -\log(2).$

Comment: Oh, just using integration by parts. Nicely done!